# Migrating to Gradle plugin 3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

The project was using gradle 4.3.1 earlier now migrating to 4.8.1 with gradle plugin 3.2.1

Project itself does not use any kotlin stuff but I keep getting this error

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':module-sdk:lintClassPath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.
  Required by:
      project :sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1
      project :sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:common:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1 > com.android.tools:repository:26.2.1
      project :module-sdk > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.2.1
```

The project level build.gradle looks like

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    google()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```

Linttool seems to not able to find kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71?

Comment: Does adding `mavenCentral()` to the repo list make any difference?

Comment: No it did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

The above lines in the project build.gradle fixed the problem.